# How to create a report that shows event label and source/medium using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm firing an event to GA that looks like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Subscribe Modal', 'submit', 'test@test.com']);
```

This tracks when a user has entered their email to sign up for a newsletter where 'test@test.com' is the email address they entered.

What I would like to do is generate a table from GA that lists each recorded email address and the source/medium associated with that event.

I'm not sure is this is possible but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know that you are not allowed to upload personally identifiable data to Google Analytics, according to Googles TOS?

> **Google Analytics protects the confidentiality of your data in several ways:**
>   Google Analytics customers are prohibited from sending personal information to Google.
>   The Google Analytics terms of service, which all Google Analytics customers must adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable information (PII) to Google Analytics. PII includes any data that can be used by Google to identify an individual, including (but not limited to) names, email addresses or billing information.
>
> **Data cannot be shared without consent**.
>   Google Analytics data may not be shared without customer consent, except under certain limited circumstances, such as when required by law.
>
> **Google Analytics continues to invest in security**.
>   Security-dedicated engineering teams at Google guard against external threats to data. Internal access to data (e.g. by employees) is regulated and subject to the Employee Access Controls and Procedures.

Please read further here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6004245?hl=en-GB

But to answer your question, that is indeed possible. Look at the area called "Secondary Dimension" on the "Top events"-report page. There you can choose if you want to see Source/Medium, only Sources or only Medium, as in this screenshot:

[image: Medium / Secondary dimension]

Comment: Thank you I did not know that was against policy.  I will find another way.